# Handling file menu when no file is picked?

Tags: java

When opening a file through the implemented-by-java method JFileChooser you may choose to just open nothing and quit the menu instead, but then it doesn't seem to behave so well.
Some example code:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.showOpenDialog(null); 
File selFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
String filename = selFile.toString();
```

What happens is that it looks like some thread is crashing when you quit the menu without picking a file but then everything still works as intended.

I tried surrounding the `String filename = selFile.toString();` line(which seem to be where it crashes) with try&catch and the result was still the same.

So what I want to know is what's causing this to happen, how to fix it, and whether I should or shouldn't care about that (seemingly meaningless) thread that dies in the background to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* check the return code from the file chooser to check whether the user did indeed choose a file or close the dialog with no selection.

```
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog();
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        fc.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
else {
    // handle non-selection here
}
```

Please refer to the official docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Comment: While this answer my main issue here, I'm still curious as to what effect does the thread that die in the background has on the bigger picture? Whatever the case, thank you for the help :)